# Are the two definitions of that a map $F:A\to N$ is smooth on $A$ equivalent?

Tags: manifolds, smooth-manifolds, manifolds-with-boundary

[image]

[image]

In the above pictures, we can see two definitions of that a map $F:A\to N$ is smooth on $A$, are they equivalent?

Comment: @JackLee Please take a look at my question.

Comment: They're not always equivalent in case $N$ has nonempty boundary. Here's a counterexample: Let $M=\mathbb R$, $N = [0,\infty)$, $A = [0,\infty)\subseteq M$, and let $F\colon A\to N$ be the identity map. Then $F$ is not smooth by the definition in the text, because there is no neighborhood of $0$ in $\mathbb R$ on which $F$ has a smooth extension _as a map into $N$_. But the coordinate representation of $F$ using standard coordinates in domain and codomain (which is essentially the same map) has an extension to an open subset of $\mathbb R$ _as a map into $\mathbb R$_.

Comment: See also [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2484727/1421).

Comment: @JackLee Thank you very much!